# Inline filtering of search results

Tags: twitter, search, tweetdeck

How to filter search results on Twitter? For example with:

1. a minimum of two replies
2. a minimum of two favorites
3. photos only
4. videos only

I have tried:

1. USD (sell OR buy) filter:reply>=2
2. USD (sell OR buy) filter:favorites>=2
3. USD (sell OR buy) filter:photos
4. USD (sell OR buy) filter:videos

but none of the above works.

Must be inline because I want to use TweetDeck.

Comment: What is your question here?  If you are trying to share the information that you've found, put the answer text in an actual answer, please.

Comment: **USD (sell OR buy) filter:favorites>=2** Is not working - that was my idea. That is what i ask what is the right way?

Comment: No because I need it on the line because i want to use TweetDeck.

Comment: TweetDeck nowadays has such filters built-in